# Создать по html шаблону генератор статей с помощью javascript. HELP ME!

Tags: javascript, html, html5, генераторы, generate

Так вот, создаю игровой новостной сайт со статьями о игровой индустрии. Хотелось бы сделать **генератор статей, чтобы не пришлось каждый раз создавать снова HTML документ для новой статьи.**
Изначально создать HTML-шаблон с блоками без картинки и текста, и по нему копировать и создавать новые шаблоны ,**чтобы потом мне только осталось вставить саму фотку статьи, заголовок и текст.**

**Можно ли с помощью js создавать html-странички???Это реализуемо? Как это можно реализовать???**

**Подскажите чайнику пожалуйста(^-^)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать:

1. как ты гворил создать HTML-шаблон с блоками без картинки и текста, и по нему копировать и создавать новые шаблоны . Это самый легкий способ если ты чайник
2. можно сделать панель админа в которую наврсаешь сайт но с возможностью изменнеия и создания/сохранения. Так более профиссонально да и в целом если попотеешь раз (создать панель конструктора), то в дальнейшем уже легче будет создавать статьи.
3. > Можно ли с помощью js создавать html-странички

да, но ты будешь писать дольше нежели с шаблоном

Comment: 1.Вы имеете ввиду копировать самостоятельно в новый Html-документ?Или с помощью js?
2.Как это сделать? Можно подробнее пожалуйста

Заранее спасибо

Comment: самостоятельно в новый Html-документ. Если это курсовая то попробуйте заипелментировать панель админа.

Comment: С помощью php?Я просто не очень представляю как это сделать

Comment: Я делал на php, но можно и на другихх языках. Для общего понятия можешь посомтреть https://skillbox.ru/media/code/kak_sozdat_adminku_dlya_sayta_na_php_s_nulya/

Answer (score 1):

Если вам нужно реально решить задачу - игровой сайт - то в наше время нет смысла это делать примитивным способом. Вы ничего не выиграете таким образом. Сделайте лучше сайт на какой-нибудь платформе типа wix или на wordpress. В их админпанелях очень много инструментов обычно, а не только картинка и текст. И кроме написания текста и картинок в вебе нужно учитывать огромное количество нюансов. Ошибётесь в коде или что-то недосмотрите и потеряете позицию в поисковиках или сайт будет у кого-то не работать или плохо отображаться.

Comment: Вы не поняли ,у меня курсовой проект надо сделать сайт на js или php) Сверстать его, я сверстала, а вот по функционалу возникли трудности.